# How to Kill Selenium "Click" Thread After Timeout

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Currently, I'm utilizing a working method for killing a Selenium `get` thread after a specified timeout that I found here on Stack Overflow ...

```
String url = "https://www.myurl.me";
Integer timeout = 3000;
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            driver.get(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
}, url);
t.start();
try {
    t.join(timeout); // <--- Timeout specified in milliseconds
}
catch (InterruptedException e) { // ignore
}
if (t.isAlive()) { // Thread still alive, we need to abort
    System.out.println("Timeout on loading page " + url);
    t.interrupt();
}
```

However, I'm needing another method for killing a Selenium `click` thread after a specified length of time, so if a click on a link is hanging, the thread will just be killed.  Basically I'd like to kill something like this ...

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(relXpath)).click();
```

Any suggestions as to how my above code could be modified to kill a `click` instead of a `get`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(elementXpath)).click();
    }
};

t.setName("runThread");
t.start();
try {
    t.join(3000); // <--- Timeout specified in milliseconds
}
catch (InterruptedException e) { // ignore
}
if (t.isAlive()) { // Thread still alive, we need to abort
    System.out.println("Timeout on loading on xpage "+ monkeyPath);
    t.interrupt();
}
```